# Javascript/JQuery FileUpload Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have built a fully functional (and very simple) image-uploading program within a webpage using PHP, SQLite and JQuery. I understand that there are very robust, easy to use free JQuery plugins out there that do exactly what I am trying to do, but I am a 'reinvent-the-wheel' kind of person who enjoys creating programs from the ground up.

My program works fine, except when I try to upload large images or many small/medium sized images. This is because I trigger the submit button using the `JQuery .change()` event on the input element and the change() event is triggered before the large image (or many small/medium sized images) have a chance to load.

Thus, my script spits out the error `Uploaded File not Found`. I want to display some type of loading .gif (no progress bar) while these images are loading and then `submit()` when the image(s) are done uploading. Is there an event for when a file is completely uploaded? How do all these popular JQuery upload programs know when the files are completely uploaded?

Comment: Here is the list of ajax events. http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: I should have been more descriptive, as far as I know, I am not using any ajax functions. Maybe it is possible to utilize the events without calling any specific ajax functions, but all I am doing is using a standard html form submit button, but using JQuery to trigger that submit.